# Transform 2nd order ode into hypergeometric equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to prove that any second-order ordinary differential equation with three regular singular points can be transformed to a hypergeometric equation? Thanks.

Comment: by a fractional integral transformation send the singularities to $0$, $1$, $\infty$.

Comment: Can you suggest some references which contain detailed calculation?